# mvvm viewmodel vs asp.net mvc viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

NO this is not a duplicate!

```
In MVVM viewModel a PersonViewModel wraps a Person model.
In MVC  viewModel a PersonViewModel does/should not wrap a Person.
```

Instead Automapper is used else it would be a **hybrid PersonViewModel**.

So the **mvc alpha geeks** on **SO** say

What is the reason that  it is not allowed/wanted for mvc that a viewmodel wraps a model?

**The context of my question is this:**

When I dont wrap my models inside the viewmodel then I have to assign all model properties to the viewmodel properties in the controller. Thats a mess. Then people tell to use AutoMapper which is partly fine and partly terrible because now I have viewModel logic in the AutoMapper profile classes and I have viewModel logic in the viewmodels which belong there.

Now I have to test automapper AND viewModels. I would like to have a consistent architecture where I test only viewModels but then I have to wrap my models.

Thats the origion of my question.

Comment: It's not a duplicate but a low quality... ;-)

Comment: well how can I increase the quality of the question?

Comment: I wish I could say, I don't get even what is the subject you're asking on. Good luck with your problem mate!

Comment: You think the problem is bad described?

Comment: I have updated my question with more info! and thanks for the upvoters!

Comment: I stated one of the reasons here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12957181/913845

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly *allowed*, but it's not part of the structure of MVC. If you start wrapping data models with view models, then you're beginning to adhere to MVVM.

Which pattern you use depends on many factors, and is often largely down to your personal preference. Hence, there's nothing inherently *wrong* in using one pattern over another, but the point of doing so is to adhere to that certain set of principles to achieve a consistent architecture.

Comment: I have updated my question with more info! and thanks for the upvoters!